# CFLAGS ignores -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to compile the latest Open VM Tools from VMWARE on Ubuntu 14.04.
Running "make" I get the following:

> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
> file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
> standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
> with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

I've already went through the available topics on StackOverflow but none of the suggestions helped. I tried adding "-std=c++11" to CFLAGS in the Makefile. I also tried adding it to CXXFLAGS but it does not work. I get the same error message.

Comment: "I tried adding" That's not enough information. Show the before and the after.